# Meaning of int variable in suffix increment operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have this code:

```
class LazyStream {
    ostream& output;
    std::list<string> pending;
public:
    //...
    LazyStream operator++(int n = 0){
        LazyStream other(output);
        if (n>0) output << "<#" << n << ">";
        output << pending.pop_front();
        return other;
    }
```

I do not understand the meaning of getting an int value for the operator++. I though it was just an indication that the operator is a suffix. How can the operator get a number? 
Can someone give an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's possible to pass that argument if you use function call syntax to call that operator. This code compiles cleanly with gcc and outputs `42`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Stream {
    Stream operator++(int n)
    {
        std::cout << n;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stream s;
    s.operator++(42);
}
```

If I give it default value, it gives a warning (with -pedantic flag) that it cannot have one, though. It sort of makes sense, because if you also defined prefix increment, then the call `s.operator++()` would be ambiguous. I didn't, however, find anything in the standard explicitly prohibiting the default value.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's the first time I've seen the `int` defaulted.

As you point out, a "dummy" `int` parameter is use to
distinguish the post-fix operator from the prefix.  Except that
it's not really a dummy: when you write:

```
myVar ++;
```

and `myVar` has a user defined postfix `++`, the compiler
actually calls it as:

```
myVar.operator++( 0 );
```

And there's nothing to stop you from writing:

```
myVar.operator++( 42 );
```

(Of course, having to do so, as in this case, sort of defeats
the purpose of operator overloading.)

Comment: C++ the language of microoptimizations, has a built in feature that passes an unneeded int parameter?